# How do you forcibly unmount a disk when you press the eject button on an optical drive?

Tags: 10.10, cd, drive, umount

When upgrading my hardware, I also upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10. On my previous system (with 10.04 and earlier). when I ejected a disk from the optical drive, the sub-folder in the `/media` directory was automatically removed. In my new 10.10 system, if I don't eject the disk using the `eject` command within the system, the disk remains mounted, even after a new disk is installed.

The new drive is a Blue Ray drive, but I haven't noticed any other problems from it.

Normally, this isn't a problem, but it makes installing applications that are spread over multiple CDs more difficult in many cases (i.e. Wine). Any advice?

Comment: I've also had this same issue with 10.10.  I'm interested in a fix.

Answer (score 2):

There's a wide variety of hardware eject buttons for optical drives.  Some of them send a software signal, so that the operating system knows that the disk has been ejected.  Some of them do not do this.  It sounds like your new system has an optical drive that falls into the latter category.  Since optical drives tend to be slow, read-only media, there's a high chance that the operating system will have cached some of the data if you were using it.  Removing the underlying storage without clearing the cache may not immediately result in the data being unavailable (although there is a strong chance that only some files, or even some parts of files remain available without the media).

The simple workaround is to always tell the software to eject, rather than using the hardware button.  You might also look at alternate input devices that have an eject button (some keyboards, or wire a special button as an input device, etc.).  The last resort would be to switch your optical drive for another one.

In the event that you have removed a disk without unmounting, it should be safe to unmount it from software independent of the removal of the media.  Some drives will automatically rescan when this is done: others will physically eject and need to be reinserted.

Answer (score 0):

Before you hit the eject button use lsof to find out what program has files open on the cd and beat it into submission.  Open files prevent it from being unmounted.

Comment: No luck, grepping lsof doesn't list any open files on the CD.